# Funcao Jquery retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu criei uma função, mas nao sei por qual motivo quando eu chamo essa funcao o retorno dela vem como undefined.

segue o código

```
function serviceDetails(id){

  //Service of the wall of cards (Grid Home page).
  var _PATH_SERVICE = _app.parseBaseUrl('{{httpsBaseUrl}}relay/moment/'+id);

  //MOCK
  // var _PATH_SERVICE = '/wall.json';

  //AJAX GET service.
  _utils.Ajax.get(_app.parseBaseUrl(_PATH_SERVICE))
  .done(function(result) {

    //console.log(result);
    //console.log(result);
    //details = result;

      return result;

    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log('Fail in service of wall.');
    });
}
```

Comment: O problema parece ser no fato de ser uma requisição ajax. Quando você chama a função, ela inicia a requisição e continua executando a função, como não tem nenhum `return`, ela retorna undefined, enquanto o retorno do ajax fica dentro do escopo da função.

Comment: O estranho, que quando coloco um console.log(result) dentro da função, ele retorna certinho a requisicao, mas quando chamo essa função em outro lugar ele retorna undefined, voce sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Como eu disse, o valor do retorno está certo, mas fica "preso" no escopo da função `serviceDetail`, porque ele é executado assícronamente. Depois que você inicia a requisição ajax, ele continua executando a função e, como não tem nenhum retorno em seu escopo, ela retorna `undefined`, o que você deveria era jogar esse valor para "fora" do done, atribuindo a uma variável global, por exemplo.

Comment: Entao, eu deveria criar uma variavel fora do escopo atribuir o valor a ela e usar? nao chamar a funcao direto?

Comment: Essa seria uma forma de resolver o problema.

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso, resolveu, mas nao da certo pelo que tenho que fazer, preciso executar a funcao logo no evento do click de outra funcao, quando faco dessa forma existe um atraso na reposta, ele nao traz o retorno da funcao no primeiro click

Comment: Eu não entendi direito o problema (atraso), sempre vai ter um atraso devido a requisição ajax, não?